# Need help with proving conditionals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Suppose P(x) is the assertion that "x is odd" and Q(x) is the assertion that "x^2 - 1 is divisible by 8"

For part A it wanted us to prove P(x) -> Q(x). I solved that one but I'm having trouble evaluating Q(x) -> p(x). Could someone nudge me in the right direction?

EDIT :

Does this work?

Proof by contrapositive:

Suppose x is not odd then x = 2m, m is an element of Z.

Then $$ x^2 - 1 = 4m^2 -1 $$
$$ = (2m+1)(2m-1) $$
We know that (2m+1) and (2m-1) are odd, and an odd multiplied by an odd is also odd which cannot be divisible by 8.

Comment: Your proof works fine. More simply, if $x$ is even then $x^2$ is even and therefore $x^2-1$ is odd, and therefore not divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 1):

*$P(x): x$ is an odd number.*
*$Q(x): x^2-1$ is divisible by 8.*

$Q(x)\implies P(x)$

*Suppose $Q(x)$. If possible let $x$ be even. Then $x=2m, $ $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.*

*Then $x^2-1=(2m)^2-1=4m^2-1=(2m+1)(2m-1)$ which is odd since $2m\pm1$ is odd and hence $8\nmid (x^2-1). \blacksquare$*